# How to find apk file in android studio 0.5.2

Tags: android

How to find `apk file` in android studio 0.5.2. I checked build file but apk is not generate.

Can anyone help me in finding this file?

Comment: if you don't have it in the module/build/apk directory, than your build was not successful. Fix your build and it will be there. If you have trouble on your build, please provide more information like errors etc

Comment: Have you checked this directory : 

your_project\your_project_module\build\apk\your_apk_should_be_here

Answer (score 2):

In later versions of Android Studio, it doesn't build a full APK from the "Make Project" command in order to make builds faster; it only builds an APK when you run the project, or use the "Generate Signed APK" wizard. If you want to force it to build an APK, go to thew Gradle window, open up the Tasks view, and choose "assembleDebug" to make a debug APK. When you do that your APK will be built in the build/apk directory in your module's directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem

I run the app once on AVD

the apk file is generated

Answer (score -1):

As soon as your build is successful .apk file is generated and it's path is like
project/build/apk directory.

Comment: I see @ScottBarta, is right about this question,  it only builds an APK when you run the project or use the "Generate Signed APK" wizard. not when build is successful.