# No "apk" folder generated inside the "Build" folder when building an APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am using Android Studio v 0.5.7. The problem is that, in the "Bin" folder my apk file is there, but it is not built automatically. That is, it shows my older APK.

When I searched regarding this issue I found that, in the "Build" folder an "apk" folder is generated and it shows the updated apk file. But I have no "apk" folder inside the "Build" folder.

So, how can I get my latest apk file in Android Studio?

Comment: Is your project using Gradle or it's imported from Eclipse?

Comment: Actually i export Gradle file from eclipse and import it in Android studio. Is there any wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550611/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare i select "assembleDebug" from Gradle. But still my apk is not generated.

Comment: Are there any errors when you build? assembleDebug should do the trick.

Comment: @ScottBarta. No errors found when i build project.

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav did you find the apk.Since i couldn't find the bin folder, and found no apk in build folder

Answer (score 4):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73370
has the additional details
There is a 'gradle tasks ' window - just like the editor area, project area, gradle console , similarly to the right side of android studio - there are commander, Maven Projects and gradle tasks -

once you open gradle tasks window, you will find the assemblerelease task - Run it and you will find the apk generated in \mobile\build\outputs\apk or \wear\build\outputs\apk etc

Answer (score 1):

I also had faced this problem .But found the apk in win explorer serching "apk" in project folder.